# tmux: How to have the main pane of the main-vertical layout on the right?

Tags: tmux

```
bind -n M-Enter split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}" \; \
    swap-pane -d -t :.1 \; \
    select-layout main-vertical
```

The above's snippet is how I am spawning new panes with the main vertical layout.
But this layout by default sets the main pane on the left.
I am trying to have it on the right.